# laravel before date validation is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have two fields, which are: `first_date` and `last_date`

These are their validation rules:

```
'first_date' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
        'last_date' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|before:first_date',
```

The problem is that what ever the input date is, I get this message:

```
 The last date must be a date before first date.
```

I tried these values:

```
first_date: 2010-5-29
last_date: 2009-5-29
```

I got that error message though the last date is already before the first date

I tried these values:

```
 first_date: 2010-5-29
 last_date: 2014-5-29
```

and I got the same error message.

Help please

Comment: You might be interested in [this guide](http://laravelish.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/compare-2-dates-from-input-in-validation-part-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update Laravel to `v4.2.7`. There was a bug with the `Before` validator that has been fixed and released only yesterday. I could reproduce your problem with `v4.2.6` but things work fine in `v4.2.7`.

In order to update Laravel to the latest `4.2` version, make sure you have

```
"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
```

in your `composer.json` file and then run `composer update`.

Comment: You right, I just updated it as you said and It worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try: (month with leading 0):

```
first_date: 2010-05-29
last_date: 2009-05-29
```

> m     Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I just tested it, the error message keeps appearing